# pug iteration - loop through object properties with dynamic lengths

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I'm trying to loop through values of an object which has dynamic lengths for each object.

Here is the pug mixin:

```
mixin gridContent(title,items,listName, gridType)
  section(id=pageName class=listName)
    div(class="grid-content grid-content--"+listName)
      .container 
        h1.grid-content__title !{title}
        ul.grid-content__list
                  li.grid-content__item
                    h1.item-title= item.title
                    div(class="item-content")
                       each item in items
                    p.item-description-title= item.content.link <-- works but only giving me 3 values I need the number of values in each object with its own dynamic count
```

Here is the main pug file where I call the mixin and the array values:

```
 var servicesGrid = [
    {
      title: 'Accident',
      content: {
        link: 'Accident Benefits',
        link: 'Car Accidents',
        link: 'Bike Accidents',
        link: 'Motorcycle Accidents',
        link: 'Truck Accidents',
        link: 'Slip and Fall Accidents',
        link: 'Fatal Accidents',
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Injury',
      content: {
        link: 'Dog Bites',
        link: 'Brain and Spinal Cord Injury',
        link: 'Personal Injury'
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Other',
      content: {
        link: 'Medical Malpractice',
        link: 'Nursing Home Abuse',
        link: 'Civil Litigation',
        link: 'Product Liability',
        link: 'Second opinions',
        link: 'WSIB Claims',
        link: 'Wills and PoAs',
        link: 'CPP Long Term Disabilities',
        link: 'Bullying'
      }
    }
  ]
html
  head
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PC</title>   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main-45b6b7cf6ab0243c647f.css">
  body

    +gridContent('<span>What we stand for<span> <span class="type--color-green">our services</span>', servicesGrid, 'services', 'servicesGrid')
```

How to make each link be placed into each

tag within the list? But the dynamic amount of them per section?

Comment: Have a closer look at `content`'s structure ... it features multiple but equally named keys. Each item will feature one `content` object with each of the latter featuring exactly the last `key` item of your provided structure. In addition the indention after `each item in items` is not correct.

Comment: Okay I changed to link1, link2 and etc.

Here is the logic im using:

- for(var i = 0; i < items.content.length; i++)
                          p.item-description-title= items.content.link[i]

Still error...

Comment: you need to iterate over `item.content` ... e.g. `each value, index in item.content` ... [Pug Iteration](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) ... and in the very first line of your mixin you might want to iterate over `items`  ... e.g. `each item in items`.

Comment: works! Thanks:
each item in items
       each value in item.content
                            p.item-description-title= value